# Why go1 has no value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject go1; // null
public GameObject go2; // null
public GameObject goTarget; // has value

void B1()
{
    C1(go1);
}
void C1(GameObject g)
{
    g = goTarget;
    // go1 is null
}

void B2()
{
    C2(out go2);
}
void C2(out GameObject g)
{
    g = goTarget;
    // go2 has value
}
```

go1 is a reference type, why go1 still use out to pass.
after finding lots of informations,I still can't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has no value because you never assign it one. There are two ways to assign a value to a field:

- assign the field (`go1 = ...`)
- pass a *reference* to the field somewhere, and assign to the *reference* (`Foo(ref go1)` or `Foo(out go1)`, and assign to the `ref` parameter inside `Foo`)

You don't do either of these. When you call `C1(go1);`, you are copying the **current value** of `go1` (`null`), and passing *that*. You aren't passing a reference to the field.

The fact that `GameObject` is a reference-type is actually completely irrelevant here. This is because of "pass by value" vs "pass by reference", which is **completely unrelated** to "reference-type" vs "value-type", despite the names sounding similar.